# What is the equivalent of module.exports for ES6 Modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

I have an existing package written in JavaScript that I'm trying to convert to TypeScript. My question is, what is the equivalent of `module.exports` for ES6 Modules?

For example if I have the following code:

```js
module.exports = function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
};
```

The only way I have found to do this in ES Modules is by doing something like the following.

```js
const myFunc = function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
};
export default myFunc;
// OR
export { myFunc };
```

Of course, this is not the same thing as `module.exports = //...`.

Which leads to this problem. When I run this through TypeScript and get the outputted code, users of the package will either need to use an `import defaultExport from "module-name";` statement (which isn't bad), or instead of being able to access it using `require("module-name")` they will have to use `require("module-name").default` (if they are using standard JS, not TypeScript). Which obviously is a breaking API change for standard JavaScript users.

Obviously, the goal here is to have no breaking API changes (and require no changes for customers code).

---

One more requirement to any solution. In other places in the package I need to be able to export a lot of different files as one object. So in the past I've been doing:

```js
module.exports = {
    "thing1": require("./a.js"),
    "thing2": require("./b.js")
};
```

So I need to be able to export this as normal without requiring the user to do `thing1.default`. This one so far seems like the easier requirement since I'm exporting an object which ES Modules seems to handle really well. It's when you are exporting a singular (non-named) expression that it gets really tricky.

---

Is there a way to do this without having to make this a breaking change to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to use the TypeScript `export =` command. This allows you to use either `require` or `import` with the module.

```js
export = function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
};
```

```js
import myModule from "./lib/myModule";

// OR

const myModule = require("./lib/myModule");
```

For more information the TypeScript documentation has a guide about [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html), and specifically a section called [Exporting from Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html#exporting-from-modules).

Answer (score -1):

Typescript recommends not to rewrite your code, but instead to configure it to allow js modules.

When we were working on converting a very large app from js to TS, we took the position of writing new code in TS, and slowly converting js into ts (but not spend a whole lot of time just converting).

We needed to enable few options in the tsconfig.json, such as :

```
{
  ...,
  "compilerOptions" : {
    ... 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    ...
  },
  "include" [
    "path/to/my/js",
  ]
}
```

you also need to update your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
   // ... my settings


   resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
}
```

You might also have to declare `require` as a function (if you are getting errors such as `require is undefined`):

```js
declare function require(path: string): any;
```

more info is available here :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

Comment: Not using Webpack for this. And already have `moduleResolution` set to `node` and `allowJs` set to true. Just trying to figure out if there is a way to do this without having it be a breaking change to API consumers of the NPM package.

Comment: what if the target es5, will it not support your consumer apps? for us the migration came when the decision was to release a new major that will require consumers to be es6+

Comment: Even recent versions of Node.js don't support ES Modules fully. It's still in `Stability: 1 - Experimental`. https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/esm.html

Answer (score -1):

Most accurate replacement for `module.exports` in typescript is `export default`

```
export default {
    "thing1": require("./a.js"),
    "thing2": require("./b.js")
}
```

then you can use them like below

```
import myThings from '.....'
```